# Can anyone recommend a legacy hosting cloud platform?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cloud-computing, cloud

I'm looking to build a cluster of test machines that run XP, Vista and Win7 with 32/64 bit versions but I'd like to build these into a cloud system.

Looking at EC2 I can't install XP and I can't see any others that provide this.

So, **does anyone know of an on-demand cloud platform that works like EC2** (per instance billing and on demand) but that would allow me to install custom operating system configurations?

Yes, I know that XP will be insecure etc and this is probably why Amazon don't want to touch it, but for my purposes I need large quantity of machines that represent real world scenarios. Hence XP, Vista and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [NewServers](http://www.newservers.com) or [SoftLayer](http://www.softlayer.com/cloudlayer_computing.html)?  They allow you to provision real, bare-metal hardware on demand (Dell blades for NewServers) which means you won't have to worry about support for odd OS configurations.  The prices are slightly higher than a virtualised environment such as EC2, but you still have the per-hour, on-demand flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how comfortable you feel with this sort of setup, you could get a dedicated server with Citrix XenServer installed and set up these test environments in virtual machines, this will however incur a monthly fee vs. billing per hour, but I don't see how else you will be able to do it otherwise, as providers can't license XP, Vista or Win7 for you to use on a server, only server editions.